# Is the hadith eesa leads prayer a general for specific hadith mahdi leads fajr?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith, prophet-isa, sahih-muslim, imam-mahdi

Sahih muslim says Eesa will descend and lead muslims in prayer.

> Abu Hurayra (R.A) reported as Allah's messenger (Saw) as saying "The last hour will not come until the romans will land at Al- A'maq or in Dabiq.......... the time of prayer shall come and Jesus (PBUH) would descend and ***lead them in prayer***......"
> ([Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2897))

sahih muslim, ibn majah have recorded a narration where mahdi leads Fajr.

> Eesa, son of Maryam (Mary) will descend, and their leader [i.e. the leader of Muslims] will say: “Come and lead us in the prayer.” Thereupon, ‘Eesa would say: “No, you yourselves are leaders over one another. He will say that in view of the honour that Allaah has bestowed on this Nation.” ([Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:156)).

My Question is the second hadith a specific case of general hadith at one. Since narration exists to prove eesa will be ruler for 40 years.

Islamqa.info says one part of revelation can make another part specific.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/138742

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided references or links for your ahadith.

Comment: @The Z, Could add refernce for first can't locate second

Comment: @The Z Islamweb says eesa will lead prayers later maybe they mean from dhuhr

Comment: F'amahoom/فأمهم means that Jesus will lead the Muslims against the Anti-Christ, not that he will lead them in prayer, this translation has a wrong context.

Comment: https://sunnah.com/muslim:155e

Comment: @AhmedAli islamweb says that eesa is higher in status hence will lead based on the same hadith